# Pass an extra param in simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I need to pass an extra param to my controller because I use same update action for many edit forms (want to know which form was used).

```
<%= simple_form_for @order,
  url: order_path(@order),
  method: :put,
  remote: true do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :status,
    collection: @order.statuses %>
  <% #pass random hidden param here! %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with a [`hidden_field_tag`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/hidden_field_tag):

```
<%= simple_form_for @order,
  url: order_path(@order),
  method: :put,
  remote: true do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :status, collection: @order.statuses %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag 'name', 'value' %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```